# How to use a library loaded at runtime in C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, gcc, shared-libraries

I currently have an application that runs on a desktop and a phone. The desktop requires a full-featured libfoo.so, but the mobile version only requires a small subset of libfoo.so. Someone else has already implemented libfoo-phone.so, and it uses the same function names as libfoo.so for the functions that it actually implements.

I am currently including libfoo-phone.h, which works as usual because its being linked against at compile time. However, when I link at runtime via dlopen, I won't be able to include the header file. Is there an easy way to make this work without a huge wrapper that makes 100's of calls to dlsym?

Comment: Even if you could dump all the symbols from the shared library, you cannot provide the prototypes to call the functions correctly, I think I would write a python script to extract all the function prototypes from the header file and generate c++ code to be used in the program, you can even make it a step of the build process so the code is updated on demand. **clang** has a nice python and even c++ interface for parsing c code, which would help making the process robust. If you can hire me, I can do it.

Comment: The statement "However, when I link at runtime via dlopen, I won't be able to include the header file." makes no sense. Even if you didn't "link at runtime via dlopen", you still "won't be able to include the header file." Header files have absolutely nothing to do with runtime. Header files are included at compile time. What happens at runtime is completely unrelated. You can include a header files, make use of its #define-s, etc., in your code, and as long as your code does not directly reference symbols from an external library, you can dlopen it, and resolve its symbols with dlsym.

Comment: if you want to link at runtime why do not you use QLibrary?

Answer (score 2):

Why link at runtime?  Just link to the appropriate .so depending on the current build target (phone vs desktop).  The platforms dynamic linker will load the *.so for you automatically when the executable is run, and you don't have to worry about runtime loading of a library.  You can include the header, reference the symbols all you want, and there won't be any problems.

Comment: Mainly because this is an enormous project and this requirement would introduce the only compile-time, form factor specific dependency. Also, it would be nice if a stripped down desktop could load libfoo-phone.so in certain situations not determined at compile time.